# How to change the onPressed elevation in ElevatedButton Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Before version `2.0.1` of flutter I was using the `RaisedButton` and there was a property called `focusElevation` to change the elevation of the button for when it was pressed. So after deprecating it by Flutter and according to the documentations we should use the `ElevatedButton` instead. But now I can't find a way to change it with the `style:` property.

I know how to change the **elevation** but I want to change the **onPressed elevation** for when user presses it. As comes from its [documentations](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html) there are some default values for it:

> The button's elevations are defined relative to the elevation parameter. The disabled elevation is the same as the parameter value, elevation + 2 is used when the button is hovered or focused, and elevation + 6 is used when the button is pressed.

So any idea how to customize the **onPressed elevation** in `ElevatedButton`?

Answer (score 13):

You can do it using the `style` property.

```
ElevatedButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    elevation: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<double>(
      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
        // if the button is pressed the elevation is 10.0, if not
        // it is 5.0
        if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed))
          return 10.0;
        return 5.0;
      },
    ),
  ),
)
```

Or you can combine it with the new `ElevatedButton.styleFrom()` property, by usign the `merge` method. Like this:

```
ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.red).merge(
              ButtonStyle(
                elevation: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<double>(
                  (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed))
                      return 10.0;
                    return 5.0;
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Thank you. But what if I want to use `ElevatedButton.styleFrom()` properties too?

Comment: To override the default text and icon colors for a ElevatedButton, as well as its overlay color, with all of the standard opacity adjustments for the pressed, focused, and hovered states, you can use the `styleFrom` property. However it can change the elevation. If this answer helped you please mark it as correct.

Comment: Well I already am using the `StyleFrom` as I mentioned its documents in the question. But the thing is that I want to change the `highlightElevation` when using the `StyleFrom`. As soon as I get the right answer for the question Ill mark it as correct for now I just voted up for your time <3.

Comment: Oh okay, currently it is impossible to use both `styleFrom` and change the `highlightElevation` but hopefully in the future it will be. Have a great day!!

Comment: Hey, I managed to figure it out and get it to work! Please check out my answer (I updated it), for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your time. have you tried the second code you provided? Because when I tried it there was an error saying `type _MaterialStatePropertyWith<double> is not a subtype of type "double"`

Comment: It works perfeclty on the newest version of Flutter and Dart.

Comment: Yea I just tested it and its working just fine. But there is a small problem when changing the elevation. If you noticed in the `MaterialButton` when you press the button there is a slight animation for changing the elevation but now it jumps from 5.0 to 10.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
    final ButtonStyle raisedButtonStyle = ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      onPrimary: Colors.transparent,
      primary: Colors.transparent, // transparent
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25)),
      ),
    ).merge(
      ButtonStyle(elevation: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<double>((Set<MaterialState> states) {
        if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) return 16; // 点击时阴影隐藏
        return 0; // 正常时阴影隐藏
      })),
    );

ElevatedButton(
  style: raisedButtonStyle,
  onPressed: () {
  },
  child: Text("click"),
)
```